# How to copy formulas down an entire column while keeping the same variables in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2016

I have a `VLOOKUP` and when I do the pull down formula copy (The black cross on the bottom right of the original cell) method although the formula copies the table array cells also change so that the range of cells.

It isn't what I need, I can't seem to work out a way of keeping the same cell range in the formula's without manually copy and pasting the formula into every cell

Forumla is as follows:

`=VLOOKUP(Table1[[#All],[Service Tag]], '[Master record on a new sheet in excel]'!A2:D30,2, FALSE)`

However, when I copy down the formula the "A2:D30" increments each time; A3:D31 etc. which is not what i want i want the formula to be exactly the same in each cell; is there a way to accomplish this without manually copy and pasting it in each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can force a cell reference to be absolute / static / locked.

The following semantics hold:

- `A1` - normal / free

  - Replicating vertically would produce `A2`, `A3`, ...
  - Replicating horizontally would produce `B1`, `C1`, ...
- `$A1` - lock column

  - Replicating vertically would produce `A2`, `A3`, ...
  - Replicating horizontally would produce `A1`, `A1`, ...
- `A$1` - lock row

  - Replicating vertically would produce `A1`, `A1`, ...
  - Replicating horizontally would produce `B1`, `C1`, ...
- `$A$1` - lock absolutely

  - Replicating vertically would produce `A1`, `A1`, ...
  - Replicating horizontally would produce `A1`, `A1`, ...

These locks can be cycled by pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> while the cursor is on the cell reference.

---

In your case, it sounds like you want `$A$2:$D$30`

Comment: You sir/madam are a life saver that was puzzling me for hours

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

i think what you may talking about are absolute references. google it. as far as the formula is concerned. you can add $ sign as an absolute reference to cell names and they wont increment, like  `!$A$2:$D$30,2, FALSE)`.